# Refresh User Session Array After Editing Information CAKEPHP

Tags: session, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I would like to know how I can make the array (Auth.User) reload after a user has updated their information.

At the moment this wont happen until the user logs out and then back in as that's when it loads the array (Auth.User).

So far I have tried a few solutions [such as](http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/refresh_user_data_for_auth).

I have also tried adding 
`$user = $this->User->field('name', array('User.id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')));
$this->Session->write('Auth.User', $user);` 
into the app controller.

But none have been successful.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're just about there. Remember that the returned array `$user` contains a 'User' key, such as:

```
array(
  'User' => array(
    'id' => 1
  )
)
```

So saving it to the session under `Auth.User` would actually save the session array like so:

```
array(
  'Auth' => array(
    'User' => array(
      'User' => array(
        'id' => 1
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Instead, save it into the Auth key and you can continue accessing it like normal:

```
$user = $this->User->field('name', array(
  'User.id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')
)); 
$this->Session->write('Auth', $user);
```

Now that the session keys are cleared up, there's a much easier and quicker way of re-logging in the user, as [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/461173/mark) says in the comments: use `$this->Auth->login()`.

```
$user = $this->User->field('name', array(
  'User.id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')
)); 
$this->Auth->login($user);
```

Comment: You can also just use $this->Auth->login($user); as this will also update the auth session data

Comment: Yeah that's definitely nifty. I'll add it to the answer. My brain is still stuck in 1.3.

Comment: Just an fyi, when you send your data to Auth::login, you have to send your user data, not your user[usermodel] data, otherwise you will write bad stuff to your auth session. For my money, Auth::login should know whether or not you're passing a flat array or nested array, but it doesn't. So, for example you need to do this: $user = $this->UserModelClass->findById($userId); $this->Auth->login($user[$this->UserModelClass->alias]);

Answer (score 1):

In my case i'm using CakePHP 4,

I've the authentication component loaded.

I'm using this code to refresh my auth info.

```
$user = (new UserService())->Users;
$user = $user->find()->where(['Users.id' => $this->userId])->contain(['RELATION1', 'RELATION2'])->first();

$this->Authentication->setIdentity($user);
```

now you can get the logged-in user's data using...

```
$this->Authentication->getIdentity()->getOriginalData();
```